# Ajax call inserts to Mysql twice after submitting form

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with a insert and update on my form that is handled by a AJAX call.
Everything works fine if the required field(s) is filled out (HTML, Ajax and PHP).

If I try to submit without filling the required fields the error message is set as intended but when I adjust it, fill it out and submit it the insert gets fired twice.

I'm new to this so the possibility is there that I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere but I really don't see it. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here are the codes I use:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="formStepVisit">
  <div class="form-group updt-form col-md-4">
    <label for="firstVisitDate">Datum eerste bezoek*</label> 
    <input id="firstVisitDate" name="firstVisitDate" type="date" value="" class="form-control">
    <small id="dateHelp" class="form-text text-muted">*Datum eerste bezoek bij klant: <?php echo $Voornaam.' '.$Achternaam;?> is verplicht.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group updt-form">
    <label for="firstVisitfb">Feedback eerste bezoek*</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="firstVisitfb" name="firstVisitfb" rows="4"></textarea>
    <small id="fbHelp" class="form-text text-muted">*Feedback eerste bezoek bij klant: <?php echo $Voornaam.' '.$Achternaam;?> is verplicht.</small>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="sid" name="sid" value="<?php echo $sid?>">
  <button type="submit" id="btnFaseVisit" class="btn btn-primary">Voltooid</button>
</form>
```

JQuery / AJAX:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnFaseVisit', function(){
  if( buttonclicked = true ){
    $('#formStepVisit').on('submit', function (e) { 
      var formData = {
        visitDate: $("#firstVisitDate").val(), 
        fb: $("#firstVisitfb").val(),
        sid: $("#sid").val()
      };
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actions/processVisit.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
        }).done(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          if (!data.success) {
            if (data.errors.fb) {
              $("#firstVisitfb").addClass("has-error");
              $("#fbHelp").prepend('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.fb + "</div>");
            }
            if (data.errors.visitDate) {
              $("#firstVisitDate").addClass("has-error");
              $("#dateHelp").prepend('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.visitDate + "</div>");
            }
          } else {  
              $("#formStepVisit").html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + "</div>");
              setTimeout(window.location.reload(true),3000);
          }
        });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
//Set empty errors and response
$errors = [];
$data = [];

if (empty($_POST['visitDate'])) {
    $errors['visitDate'] = 'Datum is verplicht';
}

if (empty($_POST['fb'])) {
    $errors['fb'] = 'Feedback is required';
}

if (empty($_POST['sid'])) {
    $errors['sid'] = 'Sid is required.';
}

//Sanitation
$visitDate = preg_replace("([^0-9/])", "", $_POST['visitdate']);
$visitDate = date("Y-m-d");
$fb = cleanData ( $_POST['fb'] );
$sid = cleanData ( $_POST['sid'] );
$stepComplete = true;


if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
} else {
    $sql = "UPDATE laadpalen SET visitDate = ?, visitFB = ?, faseVisitComp =?, fase='offerte' WHERE sid=?";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssis", $visitDate, $fb, $stepComplete, $sid);

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['message'] = 'Update Succesvol! U wordt omgeleid in <span id="seconden">3</span> ';
        }
    } 
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO laadpalenSteps (sid, datum, fase, feedback) VALUES (?, NOW(),? , ?)";
    $fase = "bezoek";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql2)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $sid, $fase, $fb);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
  
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: `if( buttonclicked = true ){` will always be true - did you mean `if( buttonclicked == true ){`?  Otherwise, no need for it to be in an `if`

Comment: Because you have nested event handlers (hint: don't do that) - *every* time you click the button, you get another submit handler.  First click, submit->error, second click->submit twice.   There's no need to add a submit event handler in your click handler - just remove the outer click handler and have one submit handler.

Comment: do you click twice?

Comment: If I remove the outer click handler `$(document).on('click', '#btnFaseVisit', function(){` and then try to submit the page just does a refresh...

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not check your browser's network console to check whether two requests are sent (which would make this a JS problem, completely unrelated to PHP!)? Or whether the PHP script, triggered with a faked POST request, inserts two rows (which would make this a PHP problem, completely unrelated to JS)?

Comment: @Nico Haase, I already checked and console returns false when nothing is filled out `{success: false, errors: {…}}
errors: {visitDate: 'Datum is verplicht', fb: 'Feedback is required'}` so the PHP returns correctly I suppose. When I then fill out the fields correctly it just fires multiple times

Comment: "I suppose" does not sound like you've checked that properly. Do you see only a single request or two to your backend?

Comment: I see only one call when I do a submit with no fields filled out. If I then fill out the fields and submit it gets called twice. If I fill them in correclty without envoking the required error it does submit once like intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using `$(document).on` ???

It does submit twice because you are calling the ajax method twice !!!!!

you really need to refactor your code !!

First, Your html should be this:
You dont need to use form in this case.

```
<div>
  <div class="form-group updt-form col-md-4">
    <label for="firstVisitDate">Datum eerste bezoek*</label> 
    <input id="firstVisitDate" name="firstVisitDate" type="date" value="" class="form-control">
    <small id="dateHelp" class="form-text text-muted">*Datum eerste bezoek bij klant: <?php echo $Voornaam.' '.$Achternaam;?> is verplicht.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group updt-form">
    <label for="firstVisitfb">Feedback eerste bezoek*</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="firstVisitfb" name="firstVisitfb" rows="4"></textarea>
    <small id="fbHelp" class="form-text text-muted">*Feedback eerste bezoek bij klant: <?php echo $Voornaam.' '.$Achternaam;?> is verplicht.</small>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="sid" name="sid" value="<?php echo $sid?>">
  <button type="submit" id="btnFaseVisit" class="btn btn-primary">Voltooid</button>
</div>
```

And in your JS code you should verify your empty inputs not in the form when you are not using it !

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnFaseVisit').on('click', function (e) {   
        
        var formData = {
          visitDate: $("#firstVisitDate").val(), 
          fb: $("#firstVisitfb").val(),
          sid: $("#sid").val()
        };
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "actions/processVisit.php",
          data: formData,
          dataType: "json",
          encode: true,
          }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (!data.success) {
              if (data.errors.fb) {
                $("#firstVisitfb").addClass("has-error");
                $("#fbHelp").prepend('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.fb + "</div>");
              }
              if (data.errors.visitDate) {
                $("#firstVisitDate").addClass("has-error");
                $("#dateHelp").prepend('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.visitDate + "</div>");
              }
            } else {  
                $("#formStepVisit").html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + "</div>");
                setTimeout(window.location.reload(true),3000);
            }
          });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but when the submit button is pressed, nothing happens. I dont get the alert and no console log. So I really don't know whats going on. As I said I'm a beginner :)

Comment: I've changed my code, try it again :)

Comment: Ok, i tried this, and it didn't work but when I change `$('#btnFaseVisit').on('click', function (e) {` to `$(document).on('click', '#btnFaseVisit', function (e) {` It does work! Don't really understand why but I presume it doesn't hurt to keep it like that? :)

Comment: no its ok, the reason why it was accepting twice was because you've added two listeners, one on form submit, the other one on onClick of the submit button, if I helped you, I would appreciate if you accept and vote up my answer. <3

Comment: Yeah I understand now! Modified everything and its working like a charm now!

Comment: Happy to hear that :)